# Latex Beamer Custom "Out of" Slide Number

Tags: latex, beamer

I am doing Latex beamer and I want to have all slides appear out of 100 no matter how many slides I have.

So slide 1 will be: 1/100
slide 2 will be: 2/100
slide 3 will be: 3/100

I have no idea to do this?

Comment: You should not cross-post the same question on multiple sites. And if you do you should at least leave links to the other post on both sites !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With up-to-date beamer version:

```
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\insertframenumber /100}
```

(and maybe some footline template that shows the page number, but without seeing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows which theme your are using, this is pure speculation)

Compilable MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\insertframenumber /100}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this simply resulted in no slide numbers being displayed!

Comment: @bvowe As I said, this need an up-to-date beamer version, not the outdated one from overleaf!

Comment: @bvowe if you want to do something similar in older beamer versions, you could redefine the whole footline, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413434/in-beamer-how-to-add-institution-to-the-footer But without having a MWE that shows which theme you are using, all attempts to do this would be wasted.